# OSX Yosemite won't show desktop

Tags: macos, startup

So I got some freeze issue and beach ball indicator was appeared for me. So I was watching rotation of it during ten minutes and then hard reset my mac. So did because I can't click any buttons or apple menu. Just keyboard caps lock pressing shows me that there is some reaction from my actions.

After reset I pick a user entered a password and then saw this screen:

[image]

And after that I saw this screen and it was last:

[image]

Comment: Seems I have this problem http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1804212

Comment: That looks like your GPU died, and it also can not find the boot volume. Did you try to boot in support modes  or from external device ? As you know hard reset is not recommended since it can create problems.

Comment: Why do you think his GPU died?

Comment: I'd like confirmation from the OP that the heavy moiré on the first picture is just a camera effect, & wasn't actually visible on screen, before deciding whether or not that could be a GPU issue. If it's not, then it's a simple HD failure

Comment: @Tetsujin yep it is just a camera

Comment: OK, then it's a drive failure - see if you can repair it by starting in Recovery Mode - Cmd/R at the chimes

Comment: @Tetsujin is there any way how to download all current files from disk utility without osx, because after I click cmd r I can access to disk utility, how can I copy HDD to external USB HDD ? Is it possible?

Comment: You may be able to do it from single user mode, but you'd need someone better at terminal than me ;)